# Finding powerlines in LIDAR point clouds with RANSAC

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-image, point-clouds, ransac

I'm trying to find powerlines in LIDAR points clouds with `skimage.measures` `ransac()` function. This is my very first time meddling with these modules in python so bear with me.

So far all I knew how to do reliably was filtering low or 'ground' points from the cloud to reduce the number of points to deal with.

```
def filter_Z(las, threshold):
    filtered = laspy.create(point_format = las.header.point_format, file_version = las.header.version)
    filtered.points = las.points[las.Z > las.Z.min() + threshold]

    print(f'original size: {len(las.points)}')
    print(f'filtered size: {len(filtered.points)}')

    filtered.write('filtered_points2.las')

    return filtered
```

The `threshold` is something I put in by hand since in the las files I worked with are some nasty outliers that prevent me from dynamically calculating it.

The filtered point cloud, or one of them atleast looks like this:
[image]

Note the evil red outliers on top, maybe they're birds or something. Along with them are trees and roofs of buildings. If anyone wants to take a look at the `.las` files, let me know. I can't put a wetransfer link in the body of the question.

A top down view:

[image]

I've looked into it as much as I could, and found the `skimage.measure` module and the `ransac` function that comes with it. I played around a bit to get a feel for it and currently I'm stumped on how to continue.

```
def ransac_linefit_sklearn(points):
    model_robust, inliers = ransac(points, LineModelND, min_samples=2, residual_threshold=1000, max_trials=1000)
    return model_robust, inliers
```

The result is quite predictable (I ran `ransac` on a 2D view of the cloud just to make it a bit easier on the pc)

[image]

Using this doesn't really yield any good results in examples like the one I posted. The vegetation clusters have too many points and the line is fitted through it because it has the highest point density.

I tried `DBSCAN()` to cluster up the points but it didn't work. I also attempted `OPTICS()` but as I write it still hasn't finished running.

From what I've read on various articles, the best course of action would be to cluster up the points and perform RANSAC on each individual cluster to find lines, but I'm not really sure on how to do that or what clustering method to use in situations like these.

One thing I'm also curious about doing is just filtering out the big blobs of trees that mess with  model fititng.

Comment: consider using PCL. I hear it's made for that. [edit]ing your post to add some "point cloud"-related tags might also help. -- maybe you also want to use deep learning to segment your point clouds. I hear there are trained networks ready to use.

Comment: I will check out PCL first. Strange how it never showed up on any of my searches.

Comment: ok now i see why, its a nightmare to install and the project is unmaintained

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz If you can link any neural nets to try I'd be greatful. I've found a few on paperswithcode and I think all of them are focused on interior stuff.

Comment: some random results: https://towardsdatascience.com/deep-learning-on-point-clouds-implementing-pointnet-in-google-colab-1fd65cd3a263 https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.12033 -- you may have to fine-tune (retrain) it for your data, of course, but it's like fine-tuning for the usual 2D applications (classification, detection), where the network has learned the basics (low level features) and you just explain new classes to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Inadequacy of RANSAC

RANSAC works best whenever your data fits a mono-modal distribution around your model. In the case of this point cloud, it works best whenever there is only one line with outliers, but there are at least 5 lines when viewed birds-eye. Check out [this older SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37535960/ransac-with-multiple-lines-to-be-detected) post that discusses your problem. [Francesco's response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37546605/9870343) suggests an iterative RANSAC based approach.

### Octrees and SVD

Colleagues worked on a similar problem in my previous job. I am not fluent in the approach, but I know enough to provide some hints.

Their approach resembled Francesco's suggestion. They partitioned the point-cloud into octrees and calculated the [singular value decomposition](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.svd.html) (SVD) within  each partition. The three resulting singular values will correspond to the geometric distribution of the data.

- If the first singular value is significantly greater than the other two, then the points are line-like.
- If the first and second singular values are significantly greater than the other, then the points are plane-like
- If all three values are of similar magnitude, then the data is just a "glob" of points.

They used these rules iteratively to rule out which points were most likely NOT part of the lines.

### Literature

If you want to look into published methods, maybe [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Assessment-of-the-power-line-point-clouds-extraction-and-fitting-results_tbl4_324592330) is a good starting point. Power lines are modeled as hyperbolic functions.

Comment: I was thinking something along the lines of your first point, however If I'm not mistaken, the algorithm will most likely also fit in the big vegetation clouds that are all around. So the result will likely be correct, but trees will most likely be mistaken for power lines too. I will take a gander at the paper, it seems interesting. I'll accept your answer. Thank you for your time.